# In latex, how do I loop through an array creating either associations or macros for each element?

Tags: loops, macros, latex

I still want to create control sequences like \ionH
which is supposed to expand to ${H}^{+}$ and similarly for other ions.
The foreach loop appears to define the control sequences while inside the loop, and I expected the "\global" make it visible outside the loop.
It didn't work.  Any ideas how to fix this please?

```
\def\Element{
1   /   H   /   Hydrogen        /   +   /   1+,
11  /   Na  /   Sodium          /   +   /   1+,
17  /   Cl  /   Chlorine        /   -   /   1-,
19  /   K   /   Potassium       /   +   /   1+,
20  /   Ca  /   Calcium         /   ++  /   2+,
}

\foreach \Z/\atom/\name/\charge/\ions in \Element{
    \global\expandafter\def\csname ion\trimspaces\atom\endcsname{${\trimspaces\atom}^{\trimspaces\charge}$}
    \immediate\write16{def{ion\trimspaces\atom}{\csname ion\trimspaces\atom \endcsname}}
}

% Without using \ionH in the text, the output looks like this:
% def{ionH}{${H}^{+}$}

% With using \ionH like below, the following error is generated:
%! Undefined control sequence.
%<argument> \atom 
%
%l.3 \ionH

\ionH
```

Comment: I have changed the problem a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following suits your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{elements.csv}
1   ,   H   ,   Hydrogen        ,   +   ,   1+
2   ,   He  ,   Helium          ,       ,   0
3   ,   Li  ,   Lithium         ,   +   ,   1+
4   ,   Be  ,   Beryllium       ,   ++  ,   2+
5   ,   B   ,   Boron           ,   --- ,   3-  3+
6   ,   C   ,   Carbon          ,   4+  ,   4+
7   ,   N   ,   Nitrogen        ,   --- ,   3-
8   ,   O   ,   Oxygen          ,   --  ,   2-
9   ,   F   ,   Fluorine        ,   -   ,   1-
10  ,   Ne  ,   Neon            ,       ,   0
11  ,   Na  ,   Sodium          ,   +   ,   1+
12  ,   Mg  ,   Magnesium       ,   ++  ,   2+
13  ,   Al  ,   Aluminum        ,   +++ ,   3+
14  ,   Si  ,   Silicon         ,   4+  ,   4+  4-
15  ,   P   ,   Phosphorus      ,   5+  ,   5+  3+  3-
16  ,   S   ,   Sulfur          ,   --  ,   2-  2+  4+  6+
17  ,   Cl  ,   Chlorine        ,   -   ,   1-
18  ,   At  ,   Argon           ,       ,   0
19  ,   K   ,   Potassium       ,   +   ,   1+
20  ,   Ca  ,   Calcium         ,   ++  ,   2+
21  ,   Sc  ,   Scandium        ,   +++ ,   3+
22  ,   Ti  ,   Titanium        ,   4+  ,   4+  3+
23  ,   V   ,   Vanadium        ,   ++  ,   2+  3+  4+  5+
24  ,   Cr  ,   Chromium        ,   ++  ,   2+  3+  6+
25  ,   Mn  ,   Manganese       ,   ++  ,   2+  4+  7+
26  ,   Fe  ,   Iron            ,   ++  ,   2+  3+
27  ,   Co  ,   Cobalt          ,   ++  ,   2+  3+
28  ,   Ni  ,   Nickel          ,   ++  ,   2+
29  ,   Cu  ,   Copper          ,   +   ,   1+  2+
30  ,   Zn  ,   Zinc            ,   ++  ,   2+
31  ,   Ga  ,   Gallium         ,   +++ ,   3+
32  ,   Ge  ,   Germanium       ,   4-  ,   4-  2+  4+
33  ,   As  ,   Arsenic         ,   --- ,   3-  3+  5+
34  ,   Se  ,   Selenium        ,   --  ,   2-  4+  6+
35  ,   Br  ,   Bromine         ,   -   ,   1-  1+  5+
36  ,   Kr  ,   Krypton         ,       ,   0
37  ,   Rb  ,   Rubidium        ,   +   ,   1+
38  ,   Sr  ,   Strontium       ,   ++  ,   2+
39  ,   Y   ,   Yttrium         ,   +++ ,   3+
40  ,   Zr  ,   Zirconium       ,   4+  ,   4+
41  ,   Nb  ,   Niobium         ,   +++ ,   3+  5+
42  ,   Mo  ,   Molybdenum      ,   +++ ,   3+  6+
43  ,   Tc  ,   Technetium      ,   6+  ,   6+
44  ,   Ru  ,   Ruthenium       ,   +++ ,   3+  4+  8+
45  ,   Rh  ,   Rhodium         ,   4+  ,   4+
46  ,   Pd  ,   Palladium       ,   ++  ,   2+  4+
47  ,   Ag  ,   Silver          ,   +   ,   1+
48  ,   Cd  ,   Cadmium         ,   ++  ,   2+
49  ,   In  ,   Indium          ,   +++ ,   3+
50  ,   Sn  ,   Tin             ,   ++  ,   2+  4+
51  ,   Sb  ,   Antimony        ,   --- ,   3-  3+  5+
52  ,   Te  ,   Tellurium       ,   --  ,   2-  4+  6+
53  ,   I   ,   Iodine          ,   -   ,   1-
54  ,   Xe  ,   Xenon           ,       ,   0
55  ,   Cs  ,   Cesium          ,   +   ,   1+
56  ,   Ba  ,   Barium          ,   ++  ,   2+
57  ,   La  ,   Lanthanum       ,   +++ ,   3+
58  ,   Ce  ,   Cerium          ,   +++ ,   3+  4+
59  ,   Pr  ,   Praseodymium    ,   +++ ,   3+
60  ,   Nd  ,   Neodymium       ,   +++ ,   3+  4+
61  ,   Pm  ,   Promethium      ,   +++ ,   3+
62  ,   Sm  ,   Samarium        ,   +++ ,   3+
63  ,   Eu  ,   Europium        ,   +++ ,   3+
64  ,   Gd  ,   Gadolinium      ,   +++ ,   3+
65  ,   Tb  ,   Terbium         ,   +++ ,   3+  4+
66  ,   Dy  ,   Dysprosium      ,   +++ ,   3+
67  ,   Ho  ,   Holmium         ,   +++ ,   3+
68  ,   Er  ,   Erbium          ,   +++ ,   3+
69  ,   Tm  ,   Thulium         ,   +++ ,   3+
70  ,   Yb  ,   Ytterbium       ,   +++ ,   3+
71  ,   Lu  ,   Lutetium        ,   +++ ,   3+
72  ,   Hf  ,   Hafnium         ,   4+  ,   4+
73  ,   Ta  ,   Tantalum        ,   5+  ,   5+
74  ,   W   ,   Tungsten        ,   6+  ,   6+
75  ,   Re  ,   Rhenium         ,   ++  ,   2+  4+  6+  7+
76  ,   Os  ,   Osmium          ,   +++ ,   3+  4+  6+  8+
77  ,   Ir  ,   Iridium         ,   +++ ,   3+  4+  6+
78  ,   Pt  ,   Platinum        ,   ++  ,   2+  4+  6+
79  ,   Au  ,   Gold            ,   +   ,   1+  2+  3+
80  ,   Hg  ,   Mercury         ,   +   ,   1+  2+
81  ,   Tl  ,   Thallium        ,   +   ,   1+  3+
82  ,   Pb  ,   Lead            ,   ++  ,   2+  4+
83  ,   Bi  ,   Bismuth         ,   +++ ,   3+
84  ,   Po  ,   Polonium        ,   ++  ,   2+  4+
85  ,   At  ,   Astatine        ,       ,   ?
86  ,   Rn  ,   Radon           ,       ,   0
87  ,   Fr  ,   Francium        ,       ,   ?
88  ,   Ra  ,   Radium          ,   ++  ,   2+
89  ,   Ac  ,   Actinium        ,   +++ ,   3+
90  ,   Th  ,   Thorium         ,   4+  ,   4+
91  ,   Pa  ,   Protactinium    ,   5+  ,   5+
92  ,   U   ,   Uranium         ,   +++ ,   3+  4+  6+
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{readarray,pgffor}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{Elements.csv}\ElementFileContents
\readarray*\ElementFileContents\ElementArray[92,5]

\makeatletter
\foreach \Element in {1,...,\ElementArrayROWS} {%
  \edef\x{\noexpand\global\noexpand\@namedef{\ElementArray[\Element,2]Num}{\ElementArray[\Element,1]}}\x % Define element number
  \edef\x{\noexpand\global\noexpand\@namedef{\ElementArray[\Element,2]Name}{\ElementArray[\Element,3]}}\x % Define element name
  \edef\x{\noexpand\global\noexpand\@namedef{\ElementArray[\Element,2]Charge}{\ElementArray[\Element,4]}}\x % Define element charge
  \edef\x{\noexpand\global\noexpand\@namedef{\ElementArray[\Element,2]Other}{\ElementArray[\Element,5]}}\x % Define element "other"
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\ionic}[1]{%
  \edef\x{\noexpand\ce{#1\noexpand^{\csname #1Charge\endcsname}}}\x
}

\begin{document}

\ionic{He}\ \ \ionic{Fe}\ \ \ionic{Kr}

\bigskip

Fe Num: \FeNum \par
Fe Name: \FeName \par
Fe Charge: \FeCharge \par
Fe Other: \FeOther

\end{document}
```

The above example reads in `elements.csv` and, for every element `<element>`, stores macros

```
\<element>Num
\<element>Name
\<element>Charge
\<element>Other
```

that captures the four fields associated with `<element>`.

Comment: Thank you.  This achieves the goal as I had hoped.